# Does putting a computer to sleep pause shutdown timer?

Tags: windows, sleep, shutdown, power, hibernate

I have a script I use to shutdown all of the computers at my work location after 4 hours that I run everyday. Lately, I've been getting reports of users computers shutting down in the middle of the day instead of at night when they are supposed to. I'm thinking these users must be receiving the shutdown command while on location and then taking their machine home in either sleep mode or hibernate (after letting the battery die... :/) and when they turn it back on, the shutdown timer continues from where it left off.

So, my question is, does putting a computer to sleep or hibernate pause the shutdown timer and, if so, can I stop that from happening?

EDIT: The timer in question is the shutdown /t command.

Comment: I assume you're talking about the built-in timer functionality in `shutdown -t`?

Comment: Put some diagnostics in your script and you can easily find out for yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Your behaviour suggests that the number of seconds in the timer is being counted from operating system uptime rather than physical system time.

In order to schedule a shutdown at a particular time rather than a time some number of (system uptime) seconds away you should use the built in Windows Task Scheduler.

---

For Windows 7 and below you can use the `at` command to interact with the Task Scheduler ([help with the command](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/313565/how-to-use-the-at-command-to-schedule-tasks)) but the user running the command either needs administrative access or elevation.

```
at 16:45 cmd /c shutdown -t 30
```

Which will run the command at a specific time.

It has the `/delete` and `id` options so you could also delete the scheduled task.

---

For Windows 8 and 10 (Windows versions XP and above should work) there is the `schtasks` command instead.

```
schtasks /create /sc once /tn "Scheduled shutdown" /tr "shutdown -t 30" /st 16:45
```

[Schtasks help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx)

---

Or you can create the scheduled task yourself in Windows Task Scheduler by running `taskschd.msc`.